# Graphic view layout in Android Studio is blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to lay out a simple vertical array of 4 buttons using a Constraint Layout. Initially the graphic layout showed the elements; I don't know what happened, but now all it shows is an empty blue rectangle. All the layout elements show up in the list hierarchy, with correct attributes—it's just that nothing is drawn for them. I have tried suggestions I've found here like changing themes, but nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".TestActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_test">

    <!--
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="784dp"
        android:layout_height="1127dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
        -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/temp_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fan_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update Temp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--" />

    </Button>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fan_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/temp_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/setpoint_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_fan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fan Control" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fan_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--" />

    </Button>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setpoint_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fan_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pid_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/set_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Temp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp_setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--" />

    </Button>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pid_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 4"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/setpoint_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_pid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PID Control" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pid_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--" />

    </Button>

    <!--
     </LinearLayout>
     -->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on with your layout.

1. `TextViews` belong in `ViewGroups`: `ContraintLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc. I am not sure what you intention of placing `TextViews` within `Buttons`, so I just removed them. Hopefully, this answer can help you decide how to reintroduce them.
2. A couple of your buttons have their starts and ends constrained to just one side of the parent, so their widths were zero and not visible.

Here is a rework of the layout to get you on the right road:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/temp_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fan_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fan_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/setpoint_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/temp_button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setpoint_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pid_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fan_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pid_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button 4"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/setpoint_button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason I tried to put 2 TextViews in each button is that I wanted one to be a label for the button, and the other to be the current value. For example I wanted the `temp_button` to be labeled "Update Temp", followed by a text field showing the current temperature. Is this possible?

Comment: @RobertLewis You can do it but not like that. The easiest way would be to use `setText()` on the button to change its label by concatenating "Update Temp" to the temperature that you want to display. This would be done in code.